# Recylcerview hides a layout as its scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently, if the 2nd item in the recyclerview is not visible to the user, a specific layout will be hidden/gone.

So this is my current code:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, final int dy) { final float test = dy;
                if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() > 2) {
                    if(mAccountLayout.isShown() && mDateLayout.isShown()) {

                        mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("SCROLLINGDOWN", "SCROLL");
                        Log.d("SCROLLdown",""+dy);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!mAccountLayout.isShown() && !mDateLayout.isShown()) {
                        mAccountLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mDateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.d("SCROLLINGUP", "SCROLL");
                        Log.d("SCROLLUP",""+dy);
                    }
                }
                    }
        });
```

What i want is to have atleast an animation when the layout is being hidden/gone. Would likely similar to this:  [Sample animation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoonooz/simple-view-behavior/master/screenshot/example.gif) without using coordinator layout.

If the user scroll slowly down, then the layout should be also slowly be hidden until the 2nd item in the recyclerview is no longer visible.

Comment: This is a collapsing toolbar layout.

Comment: yes, i just want to show the animation but i dont  need a collapsing toolbar.

Comment: Use ValueAnimator Class

Comment: @SarthakGandhi i'm not familliar with that. i'm sorry :(

Comment: You can find many tutorials on it on youtube.